# How to find new problems since latest Db2 fixpack is released?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, service-pack

A weak ago new Db2 release v11.5.8.0 was released.
There is a [list of problems](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1102545) that were solved in this release.

But as always every new release has some new bugs. Is there some list of new discovered problems since latest v11.5.8.0 release?

We are planning to upgrade to v11.5.8.0 and I would like to check all known problems to know if they affect us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the IBM Db2 for LUW [support page](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/topic/0TO500000001fUNGAY/db2-linux-unix-and-windows?language=en_US#product-resources)

You'll find a list of list of new [known issues](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/topic/0TO500000001fUNGAY/db2-linux-unix-and-windows?language=en_US#known-issues) (aka APARs aka Authorized Program Analysis Reports).

In addition there is a link to the list of [all known issues](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/product-defect-list?language=en_US&productid=01t50000004WmTkAAK) ... that at first appears broken as it only shows a blank page.  Just be patient, it will eventually populate.
[image]

Note that the list of all known issues, includes issues already fixed.